Change DropdownButton choices text color and selected text
in flutter,
is it possible to set:

the color of the dropdown choices text black
the color of the selected choice another color?

The goal is for the selected choice text to be white and the choices text be black.
right now I can change the color of both but I cant set them different colors.
code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
class DropdownField extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic>? selected_choice;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> choices;
  final Function(String?) on_changed;
  final String label;
  final String property_to_display;
  double? width;
  final String mode;
  final bool read_only;
  final Map<String, dynamic>? style; // Added style parameter
  DropdownField({
    Key? key,
    required this.mode,
    required this.label,
    required this.on_changed,
    required this.choices,
    required this.selected_choice,
    required this.property_to_display,
    this.width,
    this.read_only = false,
    this.style,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  *DropdownFieldState createState() => *DropdownFieldState();
}
class _DropdownFieldState extends ConsumerState<DropdownField> {
  Map<String, dynamic>? selectedchoice;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedchoice = widget.selected_choice;
  }
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(DropdownField oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.selected_choice != oldWidget.selected_choice) {
      setState(() {
        selectedchoice = widget.selected_choice;
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    Color textColor = widget.style?['text_color'] ?? Colors.black;
    Color borderColor = widget.style?['border_color'] ?? Colors.black;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 5.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: widget.width ?? 500,
        child: InputDecorator(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: borderColor),
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5.0),
            filled: false,
            labelText: widget.label,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: textColor),
            isDense: true,
          ),
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              value: selectedchoice?['sys_id'],
              onChanged: widget.read_only
                  ? null
                  : (new_value) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedchoice = widget.choices.firstWhere(
                          (choice) => choice['sys_id'] == new_value,
                        );
                      });
                      widget.on_changed(new_value);
                    },
              items: [
                if (widget.mode == "with_none")
                  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: null,
                    child: Text(""),
                  ),
                ...widget.choices.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((choice) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: choice['sys_id'].toString(),
                    child: Text(
                      choice[widget.property_to_display],
                      style: TextStyle(color: textColor), // THIS CONTROLS THE COLOR IN BOTH THE CHOICES DISPLAYED AND THE SELECTED CHOICE?
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ],
              isExpanded: true,
              disabledHint: Text(
                selectedchoice != null
                    ? selectedchoice![widget.property_to_display]
                    : '',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I have google and chatgpt/claude this one all morning but cant seem to figure it out.
I think its not possible but I refuse to believe that the developers didnt think of this.
Any advice is welcome!

In this approach each option has a property to show that it is selected or not. when any of the options get selected, we will change the value of isSelected to true. To make sure that we have only one selected option, we will change the previous selected option to get false for it's isSelected property.
Beside that you can use ternary operation to change the color or any style based on the value of isSelected.
If you want to see the selected option in the menu list in different style, you can follow this pattern:
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var options = [
    DropdownOption(label: 'option 1'),
    DropdownOption(label: 'option 2'),
  ];

  int? selectedIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: DropdownMenu(
      label: const Text('Menu'),
      onSelected: (value) {
        setState(() {
          if (selectedIndex != null) {
            options[selectedIndex!].isSelected = false;
          }
          selectedIndex = options.indexWhere((option) => option.label == value);
          options[selectedIndex!].isSelected = true;
        });
      },
      dropdownMenuEntries: options
          .map(
            (option) => DropdownMenuEntry(
                value: option.label,
                label: option.label,
                style: const ButtonStyle().copyWith(
                  foregroundColor: option.isSelected ? const WidgetStatePropertyAll(Colors.amber) : const WidgetStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
                )),
          )
          .toList() as List<DropdownMenuEntry>,
    ));
  }
}

class DropdownOption {
  DropdownOption({
    required this.label,
    this.isSelected = false,
  });

  final String label;
  bool isSelected;
}


@DarkBee yeah, that's right. I've added more explanation to my answer
